# I am trying to get a setTimeout on my Preloader so it shows for more than just a split second

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my code below? The timeout isn't working - my page is just showing in a split second. Thanks in advance

```html
<body onload=myFunction()>
  <div id="loading"></div>
</body>
```

```js
var preloader = document.getElementById("loading");

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  preloader.style.display = 'none';
})

function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    preloader.style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000)
};
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? The element is hidden on load, then hidden again 5 seconds later. Nothing will be changing...?

Comment: Are you wanting your actual page to show as soon as possible, but the preloader to show on top of it for the remains of the 5 seconds, or do you want to suppress the actual page content from showing for 5 seonds in total?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `window.addEventListener('load', ...);`, your content will show for 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. do you know what code i could add to fade my website in instead of it coming on as quick? thanks